# Implementing face tracking using unity3D openCV plugin

Tags: android, opencv, unity-game-engine

I want to make an android application that allows users to put some masks onto their faces. I need a face and face features tracking for that. I've looked into some SDKs, and put my eye on OpenCV for Unity plugin. I've downloaded the Face Tracking sample from asset store, but it works badly, and I am wondering: is it possible to implement a better face tracker by myself using OpenCV plugin, or it's really the best it can offer? Is the Face Tracker sample project from the asset store works badly because its developers made it bad or because it is openCV's maximum?

Why I think it's working badly: here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5aDbn5nRbY). Watch from 0:19 - face oval and mouth get pretty much distorted; 1:14 - rotation and position in space are very, very imprecise, objects are shaking too much.

Comment: FYI the best paid technology for this seems to be visagetechnologies.com

Comment: Visage is too expensive, but thank you for your reply.

Comment: I think I answered this question before maybe that didn't help. I don't know how the current openCV you are using is implemented but I am starting to suspect that the problem is from the camera. My solution for you is to go native like I said in the other thread. Since you still want to use Unity, I think making a plugin might work for  you. The problem could be that Unity is not reading the camera fast enough. You can write a plugin that reads the camera from native side then you can pass those values to the OpenCV. Since this is for Android use C++  NOT java plugin.There is a huge difference

Comment: I guess I am really going native. Thanks @Programmer, can you advise me some tutorials on using c++ openCV android development?

Comment: First understand android camera. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html then go here http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-usage-models.html and choose the Advanced level option which leads you here http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c .

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Programmer!

Comment: Not done Yet.
http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/ndk-android-opencv/

Comment: For video tutorials: Setup NDK and OpnCV on Eclipse (with working sample)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2onPuDZQVY

Comment: Android Studio setup(Recommended) https://github.com/quanhua92/NDK_OpenCV_AndroidStudio. Good  luck

Comment: https://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/cvl/cvl2013-android-opencv.pdf Finally use NDK not JNI. Follow any OpenCV NDK Android tutorial. Most OpenCV C++ code should work on Android.